# R: How do I generate a sequence of dates to populate all rows within a column?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to generate the following sequence on Lubridate

`seq(ymd('2017-03-12'),ymd('2020-02-23'), by = '1 week')`

and store the weeks generated as a column in an existing data.frame of 102 rows.

When I try to use `dataframe["newcolumnname] <- seq(ymd('2017-03-12'),ymd('2020-02-23'), by = '1 week')`

It throws an error: Error in [<-.data.frame(* tmp *, "Year", value = c(17237, 17244, 17251,  : 
  replacement has 155 rows, data has 102

What's the most efficient way to generate a sequence of dates in a column in R?

Comment: Really new to R. So would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Anything and everything about time series analysis in R can be found here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dates <- seq(from=as.Date("2017-03-12"), to=as.Date("2020-02-23"), by = "weeks")` works fine. I think your problem is the length of the dataframe you're trying to fit the data in (as stated in the error).

**EDIT**: knowing that the goal is to have the dataframe fit the new column size, here's my suggestion:
Using the method `cbind.fill()` from the package [rowr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rowr/versions/1.1.3/topics/cbind.fill)

```r
cbind.fill(a,b, fill = NA)
```

Will fill the shortest of the two elements with NA's

BTW, I would definitely recommand checking out the [xts](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034349&utm_targetid=dsa-473406570475&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9001632&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImOnQ2srj6QIVUL7ACh39QwXvEAAYASAAEgL7svD_BwE) package to play around with timeseries in R.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The latter, have the dataframe to fit the dates series is the goal.